# Using integrated terminal in a VS Code extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

There are multiple commands having to do with the [Integrated Terminal](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal) that VS Code offers. In my extension, I am able to open it and focus it using `workbench.action.terminal.focus`, but running commands in it seems hacky to do through `runSelectedText`. Ideally I'd like to be able to run commands directly without having intermediate document to simulate selections in and to be able to read their results.

I have found the [MainThreadTerminalService](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/blob/master/src/vs/workbench/api/node/mainThreadTerminalService.ts#L11) which seems to offer what I want, but I don't know how to and if I even can use that from an extension. Scanning `node_modules/vscode/vscode.d.ts` for *terminal* didn't yield any results, so I presume it is not possible yet.

Using [TerminalPasteAction](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/blob/c647ac9ced1864e2be5697e2702da1b5f3f2ee66/src/vs/workbench/parts/terminal/electron-browser/terminalActions.ts#L138) to run the commands seems as an option, but I would first have to get the command into the clipboard and there doesn't seem to be a good way to listen to the results anyway.

I know I can run a child process and listen to it's standard output and error, but since VS Code offers the integrated terminal window, it would be nice if the user could see the commands as they run in a separate integrated terminal tab exclusive to my extension. Is this possible? Will it be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this thread
https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/9957

Apparently API is limited but you have

```
CreateTerminal(name?: string): Terminal
interface Terminal {
   name:string;
   runCommand(cmd:string)
   show(preserveFocus: boolean): void
   hide(): void;
   dispose(): void;
}
```